# Two different results for same symbolic integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, fourier-analysis, trigonometry

I am trying to compute the following integral

$\int_0^\infty dk \frac{e^{i k a}}{k^2}[\sin(kb)-kb\cos(kb)]$

When computing it as-is, i.e, with the code

```
Integrate[E^(I k a) (Sin[k b]-k b Cos[k b] )/ k^2, {k, 0, ∞}, Assumptions -> 
  a ∈ Reals && b > 0]
```

I obtain a very long, piecewise function.

On the other hand, if I write the exponential forms of the sine and cosine, i.e, if I compute the following

$\int_0^\infty dk \frac{e^{i k a}}{k^2}[\frac{1}{2i}(e^{i k b}-e^{-ikb})-kb\frac{1}{2}(e^{i k b}+e^{-ikb})]$

With the code

```
Integrate[1/k^2 E^(I k a)(1/(2 I) (Exp[I k b] - Exp[-I k b])- k b 1/2 (Exp[I k b] 
  + Exp[-I k b])), {k, 0, ∞}, Assumptions -> a ∈ Reals && b > 0]
```

then I obtain a non-piecewise function. Numerically giving random values to $a$ and $b$ and computing the relative error, I get that the two values differ in around 67%. Additionally, I have the feeling that Mathematica is somehow "omitting" or "hiding" contributions like Dirac deltas or Heaviside step functions or similar objects.

My question is: How to know which of the two (if any) is the correct expression? If none is, how to get the correct one?

Comment: One way is to compare with a numerically computed result (`NIntegrate`) for specific values of `a` and `b`.

Comment: Try to express everything in either trigonometric or exponential function. I think you will get same answer in both cases. And you can always verify the reliability using `NIntegrate` as @Szabolcs suggested. To make the convergence faster you can choose the integration limit from, say 0.00001, instead of 0.

Comment: I have compared with numerical computations as suggested. It indeed points to the first method giving the right result, but I still wonder why there is this difference...

Comment: You can also use analytic `Integrate` with specific values for the parameters.  In this case both expressions yield the same result, as do both expressions with  `NIntegrate`.  The first piecewise expression agrees with all of that.  ( I just tried a couple of `a,b` values though )

Comment: Another expression can be obtained via expanding `Exp[I k a]` and it doesn't seem to match your second expression.

Comment: To get a simpler `Piecewise` expression for the first integral use `Assuming[{Element[a,  Reals], b > 0}, Integrate[E^(I k a) (Sin[k b] - k b Cos[k b])/k^2, {k, 0, Infinity}] // FullSimplify]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does appear to be a substantive difference between the two applications of `Integrate`, even though the integrands are equal.

```
(1/k^2 E^(I k a) (1/(2 I) (Exp[I k b] - Exp[-I k b]) - k b 1/2 (Exp[I k b] + Exp[-I k b])) 
    - E^(I k a) (Sin[k b] - k b Cos[k b])/k^2) // FullSimplify
(* 0 *)
```

Now integrate each in turn

```
s1 = Integrate[E^(I k a) (Sin[k b] - k b Cos[k b])/k^2, {k, 0, ∞}, 
    Assumptions -> a ∈ Reals && b > 0] // FullSimplify
(* Piecewise[{{b - a*ArcTanh[b/a], a^2 > b^2}, 
   {(2*b + I*a*Pi + a*Log[-a + b] - a*Log[a + b])/2, b^2/a^2 > 1}}, 0] *)
Plot[Evaluate[ReIm[s1 /. b -> 1]], {a, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
s2 = Integrate[1/k^2 E^(I k a) (1/(2 I) (Exp[I k b] - Exp[-I k b]) - 
    k b 1/2 (Exp[I k b] + Exp[-I k b])), {k, 0, ∞}, 
    Assumptions -> a ∈ Reals && b > 0] // FullSimplify
(* 1/8 (2 b (4 EulerGamma + Log[(a - b)^2] + Log[(a + b)^2]) + \[Pi] (-2 I Abs[a - b] + 
   2 I Abs[a + b] + ((a - b)^2 - 2 I b) Sign[a - b] - (2 I b + (a + b)^2) Sign[a + b])) *)
Plot[Evaluate[ReIm[s2 /. b -> 1]], {a, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

They are far from being identical.  (The same curves are obtained with `FullSimplify` not applied, so it is not at fault.)  Now, if the two integrals are performed for a specific values of the parameters, say, `{b -> 1, a -> 3}`, the result is

```
(* 1 - Log[8]/2 *)
```

in both cases.  Its numerical value is `-0.0397208`.  Yet,

```
{s1 /. {b -> 1, a -> 3}, N[s1 /. {b -> 1, a -> 3}]}
(* {1 - 3 ArcTanh[1/3], -0.0397208} *)
{s2 /. {b -> 1, a -> 3}, N[s2 /. {b -> 1, a -> 3}]}
(* {1/8 (-12 π + 2 (4 EulerGamma + Log[4] + Log[16])), -3.09545} *)
```

Similar behavior occurs for `{b -> 1, a -> 1/2}`.  Manifestly, `s2` is incorrect.

Comment: Note that `FourierTransform[UnitStep[k] (Sin[k b] - k b Cos[k b])/k^2, k, a, Assumptions -> (b > 0), FourierParameters -> {1, 1}]` gives a result that is consistent with `s1`.